# Show that the product topology is the coarsest topology.

Tags: general-topology

Could you check my proof and correct? Please and thank you!

We need to show that it has the fewest open sets among all topologies that contain the same collection of subspaces. More formally, we need to show that: If $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on a set $X\times Y$ that contains the collection $\mathcal{S}$ of all sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$, then $\mathcal{T}$
is coarser than the product topology $\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$ on $X\times Y$.

To do this, we will use the fact that the product topology
$\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$
is generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{S}$,

which means that any open set in $\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$

can be written as a union of finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$.

Therefore, it suffices to show that any set in $\mathcal{S}$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Let $U\times V\in \mathcal{S}$ be a set of the form described above. We need to show that $U\times V$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$.

Since $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, it suffices to show that for any $(x,y)\in U\times V$, there exists an open set $W$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that $(x,y)\in W\subseteq U\times V$. Since $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$, there exist open sets $U'\subseteq U$ and $V'\subseteq V$ such that $(x,y)\in U'\times V'\subseteq U\times V$. Then, $U'\times V'$
is an element of $\mathcal{S}$, and therefore is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Moreover, $U' \times V'\subseteq U\times V$, so we have found an open set $W=U'\times V'$ in $\mathcal{T}$ that contains $(x,y)$ and is contained in $U\times V$. Therefore, $U\times V$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Since we have shown that every set in $\mathcal{S}$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$, and since $\mathcal{T}$ contains $\mathcal{S}$, we conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ is coarser than the product topology $\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$. Therefore, the product topology is the coarsest topology that contains the subbasis
$\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: "Show that the product topology is the coarsest topology. " This is meaningless.

Comment: 1) How would you define $\tau_{X\times Y}$?

Comment: "If $T$ is a topology on a set $X×Y $ that contains the collection $S$ of all sets of the form $U×V$, where U is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$, then $T$ is coarser than the product topology $T_{X×Y}$ on $X×Y.$" Isn't this trivially follow from the definition of product topology?

Comment: Correct formulation: $(X, \tau_X) $ and $(Y, \tau_Y) $ be two topological spaces. $\Pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ and $\Pi_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ are projecton maps. Then $$\mathcal{S}=\{\Pi_X^{-1}(U) :U\in \tau_X\}\bigcup\{\Pi_Y^{-1}(V) :V\in\tau_Y\}$$ form a subbasis of $X\times Y$ . Then the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}=\tau_{X\times Y}$ where $\tau_{X\times Y}=\{C\times D : C\in\tau_X,D\in\tau_Y\}$

Comment: Please remove [algebraic-topology] tag

Comment: @SouravGhosh Could you correct my proof? Please and thank you! Because I don't understand my mistake... And I learn it and I would like to be sure about proof

Comment: How would you define product topology?

Comment: I have in my notes this definition: $X_1$, $X_2$ -topological spaces. $X_1 \times X_2$ has a natural topology, the product topology, where the open sets are unions of sets of the form $U_1 \times U_2$ with $U_i \subset X_i$ open @SouravGhosh

Comment: Yes. $A\subset X×Y$ is open iff $A=U×V$ for some open $U$ in $X$ and $V$ in $Y$ . What you wanted to show?

Comment: Show that the product topology is the coarsest topology i.e., the topology with  the fewest open sets such that the projection maps $\Pi_1: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_1$, $\Pi_2: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_2$ are continuous @SouravGhosh

Comment: Why (in anwer/proof) $U_1 \times X_2$ and $X_1 \times U_2$, where are  sub-basis element? Shouldn't $U_1 \times U_2$ be? Because in definition we have that open sets are unions of sets of the form $U_1 \times U_2$ @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 1):

> More formally, we need to show that: If $\tau$ is a topology on the set $X \times Y$ that contains the collection $\mathcal{S}$ of all sets of the form $U \times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$, then $\tau$ is coarser than the product topology $\tau_{X \times Y}$ on $X \times Y$.

This claim is not true. Take the discrete topology on $X \times Y$ ($\tau = \mathcal{P} (X \times Y)$). It obviously contains all sets of the form $U \times V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. But it is strictly finer than the product topology, since single-point sets $\{x_0 \times y_0\}$ where $x_0 \in X, y_0 \in Y$ are open in $\tau$ but not in the product topology.

EDIT: Update to answer follow-up question.

> Show that the product topology is the coarsest topology i.e., the topology with the fewest open sets such that the projection maps $\pi_1: X_1 \times X_2 \mapsto X_1$, $\pi_2: X_1 \times X_2 \mapsto X_2$ are continuous.

Suppose $\tau'$ is a topology on $X_1 \times X_2$. It is enough to show that each sub-basis element of the product topology, $U_1 \times X_2$ and $X_1 \times U_2$, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open in $X_1$ and $X_2$, respectively, is contained in $\tau'$. For $\pi_1$ to be continuous, $\pi_1^{-1} (U_1) = U_1 \times X_2$ must be contained in $\tau'$ for every $U_1$ open in $X_1$. Similarly, for $\pi_2$ to be continuous, $\pi_2^{-1} (U_2) = X_1 \times U_2$ must be contained in $\tau'$ for every $U_2$ open in $X_2$. This shows what we wanted.

Comment: Is it enough? and is my proof  bad? @K.Jiang Thank you so much

Comment: Why is enough to prove that each sub-basis element of the product topology is contained in $\tau′$ @K. Jiang